# How to copy entire directory as is (failed to preserve ownership)

Tags: raspberry-pi, nfs, raspbian, cp, ownership

I am trying to prepare Raspberry Pi image to be netbooted. I have downloaded IMG file of raspbian (for ex `2017-07-05-raspbian-jessie`) and mounted it locally to linux box. I got two partitions. Now I wish to copy them to nfs server location.

If I do

```
cp -a * /home/dims/nfstest/root
```

I get numerous errors like

```
cp: failed to preserve ownership for '/home/dims/nfstest/root/etc/lighttpd': Operation not permitted
```

What does it mean and how to proceed?

---

It was because shared directory's owneship was `nobody:nogroup`. I don't know how it was affecting, so the answer is still interesting.

Comment: NFS, by design, for security reasons, disallows `root` access, and maps `0:0` (`root:root`) to `nobody:nogroup`.